# Java connection to Oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, ojdbc

I am trying to connect my Java application to Oracle database. I have imported the **OJDBC jar** and **classes12.jar** files in my code but i am getting error **"unable to connect"** **"DB:connectDB()=sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"**

**Code:**

```
static Connection m_Connection = null;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        if ( connectDB ( "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.50.14.12:1521:pliv" , "xxxx" , "xxxx" ) )
            {
              System.out.println("Connected");
            }
        else
          {
            System.out.println("Error Occurred");
            System.out.println ( "Unable to connect PrePaid DB:SORRY" );
          }
    }

    public static boolean connectDB ( String url , String username , String password )
      {
        try
        {
          // Step 1: Load the JDBC driver.
          Class.forName ( "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver" );
          // Step 2: Establish the connection to the database.
          DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
          m_Connection = DriverManager.getConnection ( url , username , password );


        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {

          System.err.println ("DB:connectDB()=" + e.getMessage () );
          //new SMSAlert ("DB:connectDB()=" + e.getMessage());
          return false;
        }

        return true;
      }
```

**Screenshot of the jar files in lib folder.** 
[image]

Am I missing something here? your kind help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you try to print whole stack trace of exception so that it could give some idea. also can you please mention your oracle database version

Comment: i think the problem is in your driver, please provide the version of your oracle db version

Comment: Why are you loading `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver`? delete this line: `Class.forName ( "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver" );`

Comment: Database version 11gR2

Comment: @morgano it worked. can you please explain why this driver loading was causing problem, i have connected to database now.

Comment: @HassaanRabbani i think because you were trying to load wrong driver, i think the correct one is Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

Comment: `classes12.jar` is the driver for Java **1.2** do not use this any more. Plus if you add `classes12.jar` **and** `ojdbc14.jar` you have **two** Oracle drivers in your classpath, with `ojdbc14.jar` being for Java **1.4**, you shouldn't use that either. Download a current driver from the Oracle homepage. The driver class for the Oracle driver is `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` not `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver` is for the deprecated, buggy and slow JDBC/ODBC bridge which has been removed in Java 8

Comment: @HassaanRabbani it works now because that line was trying to load a class that wasn't in your classpath (that is the jdbc odbc driver, I don't know why you had it there) so an exception was being thrown at that point before you were loading the correct driver (in your "step 2") that way step 2 never got executed. Clear now? ;-)